# How can I fix the syntax error in VS Code for the ES Next "::" bind operator?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm using the ES Next "::" bind operator in my `.js` files, and I'm using the JavaScript language. This is valid code and Babel supports it, but I get a syntax error. I don't want to silence all syntax errors, because they are very useful. I just want the linter to know about this new `::` syntax.

Is there a VS Code extension that can solve this problem?

[image: ES Next Bind Operator Error]